# Need to create an HTML file that uses a javascript function to automatically send and email

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an HTML file that uses a javascript function to take HTML inputs and send them to a predetermined email address.

So far I have this, but my sendMail function isn't working and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Complete fields and click submit:</p>

<form id="from"> 

  Contacts First name: <input type="string" id="fname"><br>
  Contacts Last name: <input type="string" id="lname"><br>
  Contacts Phone Number: <input type="string" id="phoneNum"><br>
  E-mail Address: <input type ="string" id="email"><br>
  Description: <input type="string" id="desc"<br>
  Attachments: <input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="image/*"<br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="sendMail()" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sendMail() {

var message =    document.getElementById("fname").value()
               + document.getElementById("lname").value()
               + document.getElementById("phoneNum").value()
               + document.getElementById("email").value()
               + document.getElementById("desc").value()
               + document.getElementById("fileupload").value();

var subject = "email address";

window.location.href = "mailtto:email address?subject=subject&body=message;";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo: mailto and not mailtto

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings (unless you use ES6 template strings). You need to concatenate:

```
var address = document.getElementById("email").value;
window.location.href = "mailto:yourAddress?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(message);
```

BTW, this won't attach the file in the email.

Comment: Thank You! I've got it all working except for the attachment. Do you know how I would attach a document?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I don't think you can compose MIME email with a `mailto:` link.